# Anypoint CLI - runtime-mgr User unauthorized to access request resource

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I am trying to deploy/update a Mule application to CloudHub with the Anypoint CLI.

Running this command

```
runtime-mgr cloudhub-application deploy --runtime "4.2.2" --workers "1" --workerSize "0.1" --region "us-east-2" --property "env:Sandbox" hello-world-sapi hello-world-sapi-1.0.0-mule-application.jar
```

Getting an error that states "User unauthorized to access to resource"

What resource? The Runtime Manager?

I have the CloudHub Admin (Sandbox) role, which should have all the permissions for the Runtime Manager. 
Is there another role I need?

Answer (score 3):

Come to find out, I did not have the environment set in the cli properly.

Passing in the environment with the cli command handles it, or it can be defined in the credentials.

```
anypoint-cli --environment="Sandbox"
```

Also to note that the deploy command is apparently ONLY to create a new application in the platform. To update the application you need to use modify